# Validating Stokes theorem for Faradays law.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, physics, electromagnetism

Faradays Law can be written as

$\int_{C} E\dot{}dl = -\frac{1}{c}\frac{d}{dt}\int_{S} d^2r' n \dot{}B$ ,where left integral is a contour integral, and right is a surface integral.

Using two surfaces $S_1$, $S_2$, show that one gets the same result for the path integral on the left as long as both surfaces share a common boundary C, and $\nabla \dot{} B=0$

Pretty lost on this problem. I've attempted the following so far

$\int_{V} d^3r' \nabla \dot{} B = 0 = \int_{S}d^2r' n \dot{} B =\int_{S_1}d^2r' n_1 \dot{} B + \int_{S_2}d^2r' n_2 \dot{} B $

this implies that

$-\int_{S_1}d^2r' n_1 \dot{} B = \int_{S_2}d^2r' n_2 \dot{} B$

Some additional help on this would be appreciated- not sure how to get the contour integral on the other side of this derivation. .

Comment: The left side of Faraday's law is obviously the same whether you use $S_1$ or $S_2$, since it doesn't even mention these surfaces but only their common boundary $C$. The problem is to show that the right sides agree. You've done that, except for an unwanted minus sign in the last equation in the question.  That sign will go away if you think more carefully about the boundary of $V$ and, specifically, about the orientations of the $S_1$ and $S_2$ parts of that boundary.

Comment: Both where pointing in same direction, just negate one - we got there. thank you.